# Arch: sharing a raw SCSI device via iSCSI?

Tags: iscsi, arch-linux

I am working with some older SCSI devices on my Arch Linux installation. The information on the disks is actually needed on other systems. While I certainly could mount the disk on Linux and share it via SMB or something similar, what I really want to do is share the actual raw SCSI device via iSCSI.

This same concept extends to some specialized SCSI devices I may end up working with in the near future.

In the past, I experimented with iSCSI targets on Linux (when it was still called IET) but never really did figure out how to share a "raw" SCSI device as-is. I could share it as a block-level device, but it didn't retain things such as its vendor and product IDs and it didn't respond to any specialized commands (since it was simply wrapping the block device rather than actually doing a raw SCSI pass-through.)

What I'm wondering is if this is possible. Can I share (say via the "sg" devices) a raw SCSI device over iSCSI? (A benchmark here would be: can I share a SCSI tape drive, or even a scanner, in its raw form via iSCSI) I feel like I've read that this may be possible, but I haven't been able to find any solid documentation with good examples to look over.

I'm running a current version of Arch Linux on the server. I am not sure which packages would need to be installed, and how to setup the configuration files.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Wonderful idea, +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this ages ago, and in the interim, `targetcli` came to the rescue. It does allow you to export raw SCSI devices. So if anyone stumbles on this and needs to do the same, `targetcli` in the AUR is going to be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

It seems: http://scst.sourceforge.net/comparison.html that SCST can work in pass-through mode. I think it is what you need, but haven't tried it myself.